# Why WAS does not ship with oracle driver jars

Tags: oracle, jdbc, websphere, implementation

The websphere application server ships with its own jdbc provider for oracle database. That is why when we createa new JDBC provider we can choose 'Oracle'. Now if it is providing its own driver, basically it is providign an implementation of JDBC API for Oracle db. So in the IBM/Webspher/AppServer/lib directorty I was hoping to see ojdbc14.jar. But I cannot see it. It is in my C:Oracle/ora92/lib directory. Why WAS does not ship with its own jdbc implemenation just like it does with its own jdk/jre implemnetation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the specification Java Enterprise Edition doesn't requiere that the "Application Server Providers" must develop a driver JDBC for every database, it just requires that the Application Server support some version of JDBC API.

Comment: if they are not supplying the driver, how are they suppporting the jdbc API? The driver is the implementation of the API.

Comment: No, they supports the JDBC API by using it and provide the interfaces need for use with JPA, Pool Connection, DataSources and so on. Also they supports the API providing the links with JTA Impementation. Is work for Database Provider write th JDBC driver, because just they know the best way for connect with the database and the inherent protocols

Comment: @Kaushik JDBC is a set of interfaces included in Java SE, every JDBC driver implements these interfaces, but an application server doesn't need to have a driver to be able to support JDBC: it just references the interfaces. As soon as a driver is included it can use that.